# How do you configure the Antminer S1 to mine Dash?

Tags: miner-configuration, mining-hardware, antminer, dash

Does someone mine Dash with an Antminer S1? How do you configure it? What pools can I use?

Answer (score 1):

The Antminer S1 produces `SHA-256d` hashes, but Dash uses the `X11` hashing algorithm for its proof of work. The Antminer S1 cannot be used to mine Dash.